# .net core method dependency injection

Tags: dependency-injection, .net-core

Is it possible to use DI to a non-controller method?

For example, I have a controller that calls another class

controller.cs

```
public constructor(IValidator validatorObject, IClass class)
{
  _validatorObject = validatorObject;
  _class = class;
}

public IActionResult DoSomething()
{
  _class.DoSomething("myName");
}
```

class.cs

```
public void DoSomething([FromService] IValidator, string name){}
```

But the compiler fails since I'm not passing in the first parameter.

Thanks
Alex

Comment: You should inject that `IValidator` object into the `IClass`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. FromService attribute can only be applied to an action method of a controller.

https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.fromservicesattribute?view=aspnetcore-2.2

You could however inject IValidator into the constructor of "class.cs", store it as a private member, and then use it in the method DoSomething.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I thought, but I could not see it in the documentation. Out of curiosity, where do you actually see it in the above link? I don't see anything to suggest that it only works in Controllers.

Comment: Right there in the first sentence, albeit a bit swift. "Specifies that an **action** parameter should be bound using the request services." Action as in controller action. Second hint is that it inherits from IBindingSourceMetadata and does DI lookup during model binding.